# Why do we use 'code behind' in WCF?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, code-behind, codebeside

First of all, what are the advantages of Code Behind and Code Beside? I have searched on the internet and found that we use Code Beside in web sites and in ASP and Code Behind while creating WCF. What is the reason behind this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6955272/102937

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think the OP is asking the difference between code behind and code beside - the link you gave discusses the differences between configuring the service in a config file vs in the code itself.

Comment: [Difference between code beside and code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5924461/745969) - Not directly related to WCF, but could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Because WCF service is not a web page. In ASP.NET WebForms you define markup in your web page and code related to markup. When the page is compiled initialization code related to markup is generated and merged with your code to form a single class handling the web page.

In WCF the "markup" contains just declarations. It is just support file for IIS processing which will tell web server which service factory and service type must be used to handle incoming call. Information from markup is not related to your service class and there is no code merge - the code behind service class is complete implementation of the service and can be used even without the markup file which is not true for code beside web pages.